# jQuery - How to aply custom CSS to fields which are not empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, forms

I have some fields with `class="required"` which has custom css.

When i submit the form, i see an custom error message which aplies the **required fields** the css:

```
 $(".required").addClass('required-fields');
```

[image]

Now, when i complete some fields (not all required) and i submit again de form, maybe what i need to see is: in the fields which have data (not empty), should go another css. Like border green or something like that.

Is it possible to do with a `for` maybe?

Comment: it would be better for answerers if you had some fiddle/HTML code attached.

Comment: `Is it possible to do with a for maybe?`. Yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
$('.required').removeClass('ok').filter(function(){
    return !!$(this).val();
}).addClass('ok');
```

It filters all required fields with a value and adds class 'ok';

http://jsfiddle.net/cHPS2/

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the input has a value. For example `if($("#nameInput).value)` will be true if its not blank. You can add a class to those inputs.

```
for(var i=0;i<inputs.length;i++){
  if(inputs[i].value){
    //enter add class code here
  }
 }
```

Comment: How can i set inputs variable with an specific class? For e.g. with `$(".required")`? I mean all inputs with that class.

Comment: `var inputs = $(".required");` will give you the array of inputs with that class. Then you can use the for loop to go through each input.

Answer (score 0):

You may try something like following (Can't be more pecific because you didn't provide `HTML`):

```
$('.required').not('[value=""]').css(...);
```

Using [css()](http://api.jquery.com/css/) you may change the look of your elements.

**Update:**

To add a class to them try this:

```
$('.required').not('[value=""]').addClass('className');
```

To remove a class and then add another class (Also you may use [toggleClass](https://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/)) try this:

```
$('.required').not('[value=""]').removeClass('className').addClass('className');
```

[An Example](http://jsfiddle.net/74L47/1/).

Comment: I don't think this would work. As :empty selector is looking for inner html. Not val

Comment: AFAIK `:empty` doesn't work on inputs, since a value isn't a child element of input. Also your last example just removes and then adds the same class to the same elements.

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass on every input with a Jquery selector like

```
var $fields = $('.field');
```

And check if the field is required or not and if a value is given or not like :

```
$fields.each(function ($field) {
  if ($field.hasClass('required') && !$field.value) {
     $field.addClass('required-fields');
  }
  else {
    $field.addClass('green-fields');
  }
});
```

It's a rapid draft :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('input.required:text').filter(function() {
    return $(this).val() == "";
}).css(...);
```

Answer (score 0):

Form validation with user feedback is a sufficiently common requirement that you may wish to consider using a plugin rather than coding a custom solution (reinventing the wheel) each time:

http://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation